# Oracle SQL Updating a NOT NULL column with an empty string

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having an issue writing an SQL Update statement, where I need to update a not null field with an empty string.

```
UPDATE channel_mgmt.channels
    SET registered_address_id=p_address_id
        ,vendor_id=p_spc_code
     WHERE id=v_channel_id;
```

In this case, p_spc_code, can be set to '', and I am running into a SQL error when I run this:

```
Error report:
ORA-01407: cannot update ("CHANNEL_MGMT"."CHANNELS"."VENDOR_ID") to NULL
ORA-06512: at line 8973
 01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any ideas how I can get around this?  I need to use the empty string some cases,  but I am unsure why oracle is complaining about a null value.

```
desc channel_mgmt.channels
Name                  Null     Type               
--------------------- -------- ------------------ 
ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(16)         
CHANNEL_STATUS_KEY    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64 CHAR)  
REGISTERED_ADDRESS_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(16)         
VENDOR_ID             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64 CHAR)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `' '` (string with one space in it)?  If varchar, than I believe comparisons (for most cases, i.e. you're not specifying to compare white chars) work as expected.

What I mean that `' ' = '  '` (single and double whitespace) should evaluate to `true` for `varchar` fields.

(I don't have an instance of Oracle so I can't be sure...)

Comment: That works, not sure why I didn't think of it sooner, was just trying to over complicate matters :(

Answer (score 8):

If there is a `NOT NULL` constraint defined on a column you cannot update the table by specifying `null` or zero length string(`''`) as a new value for a column. Oracle treats zero length string(`''` when assigned to a `varchar2` column or variable)  as `NULL`, so from the *oracle's point of view*, these two statements are the same `set col_name = null` and `set col_name = ''`. If you want to allow for a column to accept `NULL`s you need to remove not null constraint from that column if it won do any harm:

```
alter table <<table_name>> modify (<<column_name>> [<<data type>>] null)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I cant update the table..  Is it possible to put a check into the insert statement and if null update the column to ' '?  as small cheat

Comment: No, because Oracle can't tell the difference between NULL and an empty string. The same constraint that forbids NULL is going to forbid an empty string. The closest you are going to get is to set it to a string containing a single blank.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle can't distinguish between and empty string and a null value.  It uses the same marker (one byte of zeroes) for both of them.

Comment: Ok, but how does oracle allow an insert statement to work in this case?  If I do an Insert, I can set the value in the column to be '', and I want to replicate this is an update statment

Answer (score 0):

If you have a NOT NULL column and your going to update it NULL, maybe you need to think about your logic in your application.
Otherwise, you could define a nvl(column, some_pattern) for example '???' (depending on the column's length, of course) for unknown empty Data, when you know your not allowed to insert / update NULL.

Than you have something to check for to see if something is behaving not correctly or to filter that three questionmarks in a view or something and display it as NULL again.

Answer (score 0):

your id is not null and you want to make it null
you can insert all your table rows into another table as backup and then drop your table and create it again with null able id row and insert your rows again from backup
just care if you use your id as your primary key it will be not null again

another way is use ' ' as in your update and it returns just space but it is not null

```
CREATE TABLE BACKUP(
ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(16),         
CHANNEL_STATUS_KEY    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),  
REGISTERED_ADDRESS_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(16),         
VENDOR_ID             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64 CHAR));

INSERT INTO BACKUP (SELECT * FROM YourTable);

ALTER TABLE YourTable(
ID                             NUMBER(16),         
CHANNEL_STATUS_KEY    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),  
REGISTERED_ADDRESS_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(16),         
VENDOR_ID             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64 CHAR));

INSERT INTO YourTable (SELECT * FROM BACKUP);
```

and now use your query